# Danish roleplaying forums off topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question

Concerning this question: [Where online do Danish roleplaying conversations happen?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/104757/)

Could someone explain why it is a recommendation question?

It is asking a well-defined question (Danish language online roleplaying communities which are significant in the sense that most Danes know of them if they discuss roleplaying games online). The answer might be that such do not exist, but more likely would consist of a list of one to three such discussion platforms, with some commentary on their cultural relevance.

The question is not asking for the best forums or anything like that.

I could answer the same question concerning Finnish forums and the answer would be quite objective (there are two major Facebook groups and everything else struggles or is small; of the struggling ones, one Discord channel and the Pathfinder society forum are worth a mention), and would include a brief history of how the situation came up to be.

But maybe I am again tripping myself on the fact that, evidently, "Define all the members of this small and clearly defined set." is considered a recommendation question. Or maybe there is something else I am not understanding.

---

Maybe I should simply ask about the history of major Danish roleplaying forums, though that seems a strange question when I don't know if such exist or have existed, even.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The question has all the problems of a classic [shopping question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

- Answer will be based on the answerer's opinion of the choices available.
- Answers become obsolete (in the sense of being no longer correct) over time.

The last is the worst one, in practical site-management terms. Though it's a practical problem you have, its not one that, by solving it, will create a durable, permanent knowledge resource for the next ten or twenty or hundred years or so.

Comment: I doubt that solving a problem in C# will be useful after a hundred years, because I doubt that C# will still be popular. Should questions about C# be deleted from Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy The use of C# in the a century might be less, or greater, than it is now. The same could be said of any programming language. (COBOL anyone?) The concepts that those questions address, however, probably will still be a problem for programmers of the future. Provided the answer is not a link-based answer, the information will likely remain useful for the reference time frames. In the above case, however, the answers probably will _not_ remain valid for the same time. The answers will, of necessity, include links, that will likely be dead in any extended time reference.

Comment: I disagree with the first problem, but since I feel the probability of getting an answer would be extremely small anyways, this is hardly worth a fight. I guess this reflects community consensus.

Comment: @Baskakov Useful isn't the measure I gave. It's about answers becoming incorrect just due to time passing. A fact about C# version *XX* will still be true a thousand years from now, but which forum *YY* people use will become no longer true pretty quickly.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy If the question is "How do I instantiate an interface in C# 6.0" ... then that will be the same answer in a million years.  That argument is akin to blocking AD&D questions here, because 5E is the edition of current publication.

Comment: Well, yes, the real problem is that communities change. You win.

Comment: @Baskakov That is the critical difference, yes. It's not a contest though. If we were trying to "win" and beat all other site we would accept all questions. As it is, some don't work here and that's okay, because there are dozens of forums where those questions are already on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

If what you are looking for is to meet up with Danish people online for RPGing, you could just ask about that instead.  Like, "I live in Finland, where X and Y are the major online RPG communities, but I would like to RPG with people from Denmark. I am aware of these major Finnish communities because <reason>, but that approach hasn't helped me in finding suitable Danish communities so far (more explanation speculating as to why and detailing the results of some attempts). How can I find equivalent Danish, rather than Finish, communities?".  Because this question is about *how* to find the RPG community for Denmark, rather than what site is currently used, it is likely to be accepted, and the answers received, even if they don't link directly to some such site (though they may well do so), should help you find what you are looking for.

Comment: Makes me wonder if we should/could have regional forum lists for the non-English world.

Comment: @doppelgreener I think "I've been redirected to a forum" is a good resource question, maybe "I've been redirected to a forum and I am fluent in a non-English language" could be another one, to specifically encourage users to post their region-specific knowledge there? idk.  Something to think about, anyways.